# I am struggling to get back into Windows. (Dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bootloader, bios, grub-efi

I had a rough night of trying to figure this out.

I was trying to switch back to Windows, but upon switching back I was prompted with bitlocker. It was accompanied with "Secure Boot Policy has unexpectedly changed." I messed with my BIOS settings until I could get it to work. I then arrived at a "Dell SupportAssist Recovery" screen for a while.

Eventually, switching from ACHI to RAID ON did it. I successfully was able to get back to Windows.

However, Grub now did not show up nor did Ubuntu show up in the boot menu. In an attempt to fix this, I did "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" in CMD. After doing this and rebooting my computer, I returned to the "Dell SupportAssist Recovery" screen.

After some more tinkering in the BIOS, adding shimx64.efi to the boot fixed it. My grub showed up and I can now get back into Ubuntu.

I just ran boot-repair on Ubuntu to see if that would fix Windows Boot, but it didn't. "Repair Windows boot files" is greyed out.

I am now terrified to mess with anymore settings in the BIOS so now I just wan't some advice. How can I get back into windows?

Edit: Boot-repair output as requested http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zp3DqWzjZn/

Comment: Please post a link to the boot-repair output.  That gives a lot of useful information about your exact situation.

Comment: I added the requested boot-repair output

Comment: You normally have to change to AHCI mode for drives, but have to install the AHCI driver into Windows first. Dell also needs UEFI update & SSD firmware update. And then in Windows you have to have fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions What model Dell?

Comment: Dell XPS 13 9370 (2018 model)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get back into Windows!

What I did:

1) I found my BitLocker key on my Microsoft account

2) I went into safemode, which needed the BitLocker key, and suspended BitLocker.

3) restarted computer, and I was back in Windows. Additionally, I turned off fast start up, but I don't know if that changed anything.